# Graphics FillEllipse in Picturebox save state

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox

I create graphics thru Graphics.FillEllipse(...) which is drawn on Picturebox. After all drawing is done I would like to save current state of Picturebox with points drawn. Can someone point me to right direction, or what is the best approach to achieve desired functionality?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms painting on controls (including of course PictureBox) is immediate mode drawing. Whatever you are drawing must be repainted in some event handler, or it is lost on the next repaint. Typically the `Control.Paint` event. Perhaps you should move the drawing logic into some method that takes a `Graphics` instance as a parameter. When you want to draw to a bitmap, for example, you can create a graphics object from the bitmap using `Graphics.FromImage(...)` and pass it to the painting method. Whatever you "paint" in the bitmap stays in the bitmap: no need to repaint. Then you can save or do whatever you want with the bitmap.

See immediate versus retained mode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx